# Group By not using index

Tags: sql, oracle, database-indexes

There is a table which has trades and its row count is 220 million, one of column is `counterparty`. The column is indexed. If I run a normal query like:

```
select * 
  from <table> 
 where counterparty = 'X'
```

The plan shows it uses index. Where as if I use group by on same column, it doesn't use index and does table scan. i.e.: for below query:

```
select counterparty, count(*)
  from <table>
 group by counterparty
```

Could you please advise, why it's not using the index for `group by`? FYI - I have already run the db stats.

FYI - the plan for 1st and second query is shown below:

Note - we are migrating data from Sybase to oracle, when I use same `group by` in Sybase with same indexes. The query uses indexes, but not in oracle.

### First

```
Plan hash value: 350128866

| Id  | Operation                   | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                     |  2209 |  1469K|   914   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| FXCASHTRADE         |  2209 |  1469K|   914   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SCB_FXCASHTRADE_002 |  2209 |       |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

    2 - access("COUNTERPARTY"='test')
```

### Second

```
> Plan hash value: 2920872612

| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |   100K|  2151K|       |  6558K  (1)| 00:00:38 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |             |   100K|  2151K|  6780M|  6558K  (1)| 00:00:38 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| FXCASHTRADE |   221M|  4643M|       |  6034K  (1)| 00:00:35 |
```

Comment: Is `counterparty` a nullable column?

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes it is nullable column..But is it thumb rule group by will not be used on all columns which are nullable? or it depends on optimiser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to make an educated guess and say that `counterparty` is defined as a nullable column.  As such, Oracle can't solely rely on the index to generate the results of your `group by` query, since null values need to be included in the results, but (Oracle) indexes don't include null values.  With that in mind, a full table scan makes sense.

If there is no good reason for `counterparty` to be nullable, go ahead and make it `not null`. The execution plan should then change to use the index as expected.

Alternatively, if you can't make that change, but you don't care about null values for this particular query, you can tweak the query to filter our null values explicitly. This should also result in a better execution plan.

```
select counterparty, count(*)
  from tbl
 where counterparty is not null -- add this filter
 group by counterparty
```

Note: I'm no Sybase expert, but I assume that indexes include null values.  Oracle indexes do not include null values. That would explain the difference in execution plan between both databases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did help. After i added not null, it started using index. Sorry, But i have one more question : is it thumb rule, that if a column has null then group by on that column will not use index?  I used the same query on another column which doesnt has "not null" constraint, but a group by on that column uses the index(different one though).. So I am bit confused, how optimiser works.

Comment: Can't say without seeing the query. My guess is that the query must have some filtering clause that implicitly makes it impossible for null values to be returned. If that's the case, Oracle would be able to take advantage of the index.  But yeah, I would say that the rule of thumb is that, if you have a query that groups by an indexed column where the result of the query may return null values for that column, then don't expect the optimizer to use the index.